# Hoeffding’s inequality extension

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, machine-learning

In Hoeffding’s inequality we assume that the random variables $X_i$ ,$i=1,..,n$ are i.i.d. and bounded . Is there any extension to Hoeffding’s inequality  for the case that $X_i$ are identically disributed but not independent?

Thanks

Comment: Azuma's inequality.

Comment: @Augustin , I edited my question a little bit, Azuma's inequality is for the case that X is a martingale no?

Comment: You will need some sort of control over their dependence.